# How to select value from spinner then check to MySql

Tags: android, mysql, spinner

I made the booking application, I wanted to check whether the departures are available. I have managed to display data from mysql to a spinner. the problem is how to save the selection of the spinner, then do a check to mysql? sorry for asking dumb question. i really appreciate your answer, thanks :)

here the code

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, content);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner02);
adapter .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: here the code Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, content);
  adapter
    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner02);
  adapter
    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
  spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);

Answer (score 1):

implement your class with **AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener** and overide onItemSelected function

```
Spinner spin1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spnfirstyear);
spin1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
//Overide
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int arg2,
long arg3)
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

item = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
//do some mysql in item
  doDatabase(item);

}
```

Comment: Not to be too fussy, but in the "do some mysql" line, that should be done in a separate thread or asynctask, to not tie up the UI thread.

Comment: you dont need to put it into a new thread. you could just pass it to a function

Comment: If this is done on the UI thread then it may be a prolem for the user, since it will be calling to a server on the UI thread.  Ideally, no urls should be called from the UI thread.